# Free GeoData (Capitals, POIs, ...) database

Tags: database, web-services

Does anybody know a free geodata database that can be also be used for commercial purposes (something that is licenced under Creative Commons license)?

I'd need GeoData like capitals, poi's, .. all around the world. The data should at least include Name, Country, Coordinates (lat / lon).

thx :)

Answer (score 2):

Try [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/). It doesn't have POI but otherwise it is very complete.

Comment: GeoNames seems to be nice, any more tips?